# SetFileAttributes function returns unexpected error code ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, windows

I have a problem with unexpected error code returned after executing function SetFileAttributes in Windows 10.

My scenario in below:

1.Create a shared folder on a server with Read Only permission.
2.Run below code to set Hidden attribute for shared folder on Windows 10, Windows Server 2012 or higher

=> Variable errCode has ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER value instead of ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    const char * sharedFolder = "\\\\server\\sharedFolder";
    DWORD attFolder = GetFileAttributes(sharedFolder);
    DWORD errCode = 0;
    if( 0 == SetFileAttributes(sharedFolder, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN))
    {
        errCode = GetLastError();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unexpected error code ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER returned once i execute combination of GetFileAttributes and SetFileAttributes as above. If i only execute 1 function SetFileAttributes, GetLastError() function returns right error code ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

This issue does not happen on Window 7 and i do not know exactly what Windows API has changed on new version.

Could you help to explain my issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You text says set hidden, your code says set readonly. You're not checking the return value of either call properly, so it could be succeeding and GetLastError could be anything since you shouldn't be calling it in the case of success.

Comment: Hi @RetiredNinja, Sorry for my mistake in source code. I have updated. I expect SetFileAttributes does not return success

Comment: Does GetFileAttributes succeed? Check the returned code for INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES

Comment: Hi @Icarus3. GetFileAttributes returns succeed in this case and does not have error code.